# Pre-populated contact form (Constant Contact and WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, constantcontact

A client has a cool idea for a custom contact form but I'm not really sure how to set it up, maybe if I give some info about what we are trying to do someone can let me know if this is possible and point me in the right direction.  (I'm not really sure how to access the API, or if it is necessary)

So anyway the client sends out email newsletters to several large lists of subscribers, and they often include product info for featured products and sales (they are a wine store).  There is also a "wine locator" form on the website (using the cForms plugin in wordpress), this is where people can enquire about the availability of a certain wine or other product, or get general product advice.

What the client would like to have is a form on the website that they can link to the product info in their email campaigns, so that the contact can click on the products link and be taken to a pre-populated locator form on the clients website with the contact's email and first and last name taken from constant contact, and with the particular product name entered in the wine name text field.

Any Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pre populate the link like so:

```css
http://yourdomain.gov?firstName=Name&amp;lastName=Surname&amp;email=email.address.gov@thedomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If the links are on the form

```html
http://winecompany.com/formurl?email=name@domain.com&name=name&wine=productname
```

then you could populate the form from the URI (like `$_GET` in PHP)